# Power On Self Test (POST) test on computer motherboard... How do you start the cycle?

Tags: reset, motherboard

Not entirely sure this question is the right match for this forum, but hey, electrons are definitely involved!

I'm working on some defective computers.  An obvious first step is to plug a computer into a monitor, keyboard, mouse;  turn it on and see what happens.  If you get a display, awesome!

If however you get absolutely no display at all, where should you turn next?  The next step could be to use an electrical engineering troubleshooting tool, the Power On Self Test (POST) tester.  The POST tester is a small card that plugs into a computer's motherboard (// or ISA or PCI port) then enables the engineer to analyse a self test startup on the computer.   The board also includes indicator LED's that determine the state of the powersupply (Voltage -12v, +12v, +5v and +3.3v)  On my tester there are also indicator lights for Clock (Bus Clock), IRDY (message ready), FRAME (Frame Periods ?H) and RESET.

[image]

The board reads out a two digit hex code, and / or beep codes via a speaker.  There is a lot of info available on analysis of different codes. I've tested the POST card on a known good computer and the test card works fine there.  In fact the POST test on the known good machine starts up immediately upon power on.

My problem is: I can't get to the POST test starting line on the two machines I'm working on.  Self test never starts.  Display stuck on `--` and the RESET light stays on all the time.  I have this same result on not one but both computers.  All voltages indicate good power supply.

The whole thing is baffling.  Anybody been here before?  On one machine, with an Intel Desktop Motherboard PN: D945GCL I've obtained the manual, jumper'd the reset selectors, but nothing I do gets it to jump into POST mode. Oh, and I'm aware of potential capacitor quality issues.  I've done a careful visual inspection of all the capacitors on both motherboards and see nothing amiss.  I've also tested the CMOS batteries, good charge there.

Anybody been here before?  Any ideas on how to proceed?

An if this posting doesn't belong in this forum can you recommend an alternative?

Many thanks, 
Zip.

Followup Questions: The white cable is to used connect the speaker on the tester card to the speaker output connector on the motherboard, in the event that there is no speaker already on the motherboard.  It turns out both of my motherboards already have speakers on them, so that white cable isn't used.

And hey, nobody asked but the reason we're screwing around with old desktop computers in the first place is for controlling a CNC vertical milling machine!

Update March 2015.  I finally got my hands on an additional power supply with compatible outputs.  Wow!  Even though the POST tester card indicated all good voltage supply outputs on the original machine, swapping the power supply totally worked to correct this issue.  Info offered up in case anybody else gets here.

Comment: This is due to a possible short in the motherboard.
As you told that /RESET stays on all the time.

Comment: What does the white cable connect to? I worry that you might be mislead about the full capabilities of this product. There is only so much information about a computer's boot cycle that can be obtained from a PCI or ISA slot. One needs only to look at their pinout and specification to get the limitations.

Comment: You are correct.  It may not be the do all, be all repair diagnostic tool.  It is a place to start.  And it does seem to indicate well on the operational computer that I used to validate that the tool is working.  I will tackle the power supply test tomorrow.. Not all power supplies have the same hard shell connector and wiring logic to the motherboard.  Gotta check that everything seems coherent first.  Is there an industry standard on what wire goes where in the hardshell connector?  I assume not as one of these machines has two more pins in the connector than does the other.

Comment: You must know first what hardware is required to be operational to achieve "post". From what I know so far a minimum is, you have to have a working CPU connected with its pins proper, that cpu has to have some working memory, and of course you have to have  working power. Once you have that then the board only gives you some view, and if you can get a view on a monitor instead you can get somewhere. Cool board but I am agreeing with  lm317 it is only going to get you so far.

Comment: Does that POST card have the option to toggle whether it's active or passive?  I know one of the POST cards I've used you had to toggle the mode (rarely) on some systems.

Answer (score 2):

The POST card displays writes to I/O port 0x80.

If this never happens, it won't display any numbers.

Likely, the culprit is a bad CPU, CPU unable to communicate with rest of board due to broken traces, bad chipset, or power issues.

It's also possible the BIOS is screwed up (wrongly flashed BIOS, bad BIOS chip, or bad communication with BIOS chip) to the point where no meaningful code is executing on power on.  If this old motherboard had a DIP or PLCC style BIOS you could try reprogramming it with a known good image with an EEPROM burner or switch it out with a known working one from an identical motherboard.

It's also possible the slot you have it plugged into is bad.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured that its either motherboard, CPU, bios or power supply.  One machine I'm working on used to work, I can personally vouch for that.  Nothing external has changed, its not working now.    Haven't yet done a power supply swap & test.  So the question is.. what goes bad over time?  Bad capacitors on the motherboard or within the power suppy is a likely culprit (or perhaps bad CPU cooling fan leading to a CPU overheat failure?)  Bad slot? I doubt it, but I have others.. After all I removed a perfectly functional phone modem card from that slot :^)

Comment: Would mostly suspect the power supply.  Bad power supply can do all kinds of weird things so it may be that.  Surges and such may also damage components randomly.